# Cannot Resolve Method getContext() in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement GCM Push notification and try to get Android emulator id, and add the following code, but it shows me the following error. I cam relatively new on this platform.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String android_id= Settings.Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

}
```

[image]

Comment: try with "this" on place of getContext()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[getContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) method available in View class. Use `MainActivity.this` to access `getContentResolver` method:

```
String android_id= Settings.Secure.getString(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(),
                                             Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)
```

Answer (score 4):

Hey here is the solution for your question:-

> You are using **activity** so You **don't need** to use `getcontext()` or `this`
>
> Just use **below** line of code to get you the string:-
>
> ```
> String string =Settings.Secure.getString( getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this`

```
 String android_id= Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```